# Vizualizing relationships in a network or pathway kind of graph

Tags: r, networking, visualization, igraph

I have data that shows the relationship of
exposure -> intermediates -> outcome
My goal is to visualize this data with a plot that looks like the following. I only have one exposure for now(physical activity) but multiple intermediates and one final outcome (Breat cancer).  The arrows should be colored by a coloring variable(direction) and size with a size variable(exposure_int_es). The nodes should be labeled(Exposure, Outcome) and the arrows should contain effect sizes and 95%CI text labels.

[image]

Below, I have added a reproducible dataset. I would be very grateful if anyone can help with this.

```
#Reproducible datasets
    data <-read.table(
text = "Author Exposure Outcome Pathway exp_in_es_measure exposure_int_es exposure_int_lower exposure_it_higher exp_int_grade exp_int_n_studies
    Swain_CT_2023 Physical_activity CRP Inflammation SMD -0.27 -0.62 0.08 Low 12
    Swain_CT_2023 Physical_activity TNF_alpha Inflammation SMD -0.63 -1.04 -0.22 Moderate 8
    Swain_CT_2023 Physical_activity IL-6 Inflammation SMD -0.55 -0.97 -0.13 Moderate 11
    Swain_CT_2023 Physical_activity Adiponectin Inflammation SMD 0.01 -0.14 0.17 High 5
    Swain_CT_2023 Physical_activity Leptin Inflammation SMD -0.5 -1.1 0.09 Low 4
    Lou_MWC_2023 CRP Breast_Cancer Inflammation RR 1.13 1.01 1.26 Moderate 16
    Lou_MWC_2023 TNF_alpha Breast_Cancer Inflammation RR 0.84 0.57 1.1 Moderate 4
    Lou_MWC_2023 IL-6 Breast_Cancer Inflammation RR 1.04 0.66 1.42 Very_low 3
    Lou_MWC_2023 Adiponectin Breast_Cancer Inflammation RR 0.76 0.61 0.91 Moderate 8
    Lou_MWC_2023 Leptin Breast_Cancer Inflammation RR 0.9 0.63 1.18 Low 8",
    header = TRUE
      )
    
    # Function to determine the direction of association
    get_direction <- function(es_measure, lower, upper, effect_type) {
      if (effect_type == "SMD") {
        if (es_measure > 0 & lower > 0 & upper > 0) {
          return("Positive")
        }
        else if (es_measure < 0 & lower < 0 & upper < 0) {
          return("Negative")
        }
        else{
          return("Null")
        }
      }
      else if (effect_type == "RR") {
        if (es_measure > 1 & lower > 1 & upper > 1) {
          return("Positive")
        }
        else if (es_measure < 1 & lower < 1 & upper < 1) {
          return("Negative")
        }
        else {
          return("Null")
        }
      }
    }
# Determine the direction of association

data$direction <- with(data, mapply(get_direction, exposure_int_es, 
                                    exposure_int_lower, exposure_it_higher, 
                                    effect_type = exp_in_es_measure))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a substantial task to take your data and generate the type of graph you are looking for, though it can be done. Your data is already in the form of an edge list, but you need to calculate all the relevant edge attributes before plotting:

```r
library(tidyverse)

graph_data <- data %>%
  mutate(label = glue::glue("{exp_in_es_measure}: {exposure_int_es} ", 
                          "({exposure_int_lower} - {exposure_it_higher})")) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("exposure", ignore.case = FALSE), 
                ~ifelse(exp_in_es_measure == "SMD",exp(.x), .x))) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("exposure", ignore.case = FALSE), log)) %>%
  mutate(effect_size = exposure_int_es) %>%
  mutate(significant = sign(exposure_int_lower) == sign(exposure_it_higher)) %>%
  mutate(effect = ifelse(significant, 
                         ifelse(effect_size > 0, "Positive", "Negative"), 
                         "None")) %>%
  select(Exposure, Outcome, effect, effect_size, label)
```

This gives us:

```r
graph_data
#>             Exposure       Outcome   effect effect_size
#> 1  Physical_activity           CRP     None -0.27000000
#> 2  Physical_activity     TNF_alpha Negative -0.63000000
#> 3  Physical_activity          IL-6 Negative -0.55000000
#> 4  Physical_activity   Adiponectin     None  0.01000000
#> 5  Physical_activity        Leptin     None -0.50000000
#> 6                CRP Breast_Cancer Positive  0.12221763
#> 7          TNF_alpha Breast_Cancer     None -0.17435339
#> 8               IL-6 Breast_Cancer     None  0.03922071
#> 9        Adiponectin Breast_Cancer Negative -0.27443685
#> 10            Leptin Breast_Cancer     None -0.10536052
#>                         label
#> 1   SMD: -0.27 (-0.62 - 0.08)
#> 2  SMD: -0.63 (-1.04 - -0.22)
#> 3  SMD: -0.55 (-0.97 - -0.13)
#> 4    SMD: 0.01 (-0.14 - 0.17)
#> 5     SMD: -0.5 (-1.1 - 0.09)
#> 6      RR: 1.13 (1.01 - 1.26)
#> 7       RR: 0.84 (0.57 - 1.1)
#> 8      RR: 1.04 (0.66 - 1.42)
#> 9      RR: 0.76 (0.61 - 0.91)
#> 10      RR: 0.9 (0.63 - 1.18)
```

Now we convert this to a graph and plot using ggraph:

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(ggraph)

as_tbl_graph(graph_data) %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  mutate(type = c("Exposure", rep("Intermediates", 5), "Outcome")) %>%
  ggraph() +
  geom_edge_fan(aes(label = label, color = effect, width = effect_size),
                arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(0.25, "cm")), 
                end_cap = circle(1.7, "cm"), angle_calc = "along",
                label_dodge = unit(0.35, "cm")) +
  geom_node_point(aes(fill = type), shape = 21, size = 40, color = "white") +
  geom_node_point(fill = "white", shape = 21, size = 32, color = "white") +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = gsub("_", "\n", name)), fontface = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.margin = margin(50, 50, 50, 50)) +
  scale_edge_color_manual(values = c("red3", "gray", "green4")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange3", "purple4", "deepskyblue4")) +
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0.5, 3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much @Allan. This was really helpful! May I ask one Q? How do you change the font sizes of the text labels on the arrow?  I thought there would be a font size argument in `geom_edge_fan()` but I can't find it.

Comment: @user115916 it's `label_size`. Try for example `geom_edge_fan(label_size = 10, ...`